# Is addslashes() safe to prevent XSS in a HTML attribute?

Tags: php, javascript, security, xss

I'm having to work on an old web app that a previous developer left. It is using addslashes() to prevent XSS on a HTTML attribute.

Here is an example:

```
<?php
  // all $_POST vars are put through addslashes()

  echo "<input type='hidden' value='" . $_POST['id'] . "' />";
?>
```

Is this vulnerable to XSS? Is there any way javascript can run in a value attribute like it can in an src attribute for example, src='javascript:alert(99)'. Or can the value attribute be broken out of and then script tags can be inserted?

Edit: Thanks to Quentin, I believe it is vulnerable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is addslashes() safe to prevent XSS in a HTML attribute?

It is highly ineffective.

> Is this vulnerable to XSS?

Yes.

> Is there any way javascript can run in a value attribute like it can in an src attribute for example, src='javascript:alert(99)'.

No

> Or can the value attribute be broken out of and then script tags can be inserted?

The data just has to include a `"` and the attribute is broken out of.

Use `htmlspecialchars` when you want to insert an arbitrary string into an attribute value.

Comment: Using a double or single quote isn't breaking out, it is simply escaped. Is it really vulnerable to XSS?

Comment: @user995579 — It isn't escaped. It just has a slash before it. That has no more significance then putting a `d` before it in HTML.

Comment: Yes it puts a slash before it. This is keeping all user input within the value attribute and so I don't think it can be broken out of.

Comment: @user995579 — No! It doesn't! A slash is **not an escape character** in HTML!

Comment: My XSS attack skills aren't up to putting together a real test case at this time of the morning, but [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ewya8/) demonstrates that a slash is not an HTML escape character.

Comment: Here is a test site for testing issues like that: http://www.insecurelabs.org/Task/Rule2

Answer (score 3):

`addslashes()` is not appropriate for this task. Use `htmlspecialchars()` or `htmlentities()` instead, eg

```
<input type="hidden"
       value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['id'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') ?>">
```