# Sentence stops before quotation mark on copyToClipboard

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to make a button to copy the text I have in a textarea.
This is my html code:

```
<textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Text goes here...." name="text" id="text_general" disabled><?php echo $text_general; ?></textarea>
<button class="btn btn-primary copied" data-clipboard-text="<?php echo $text_general; ?>" onclick="copyToClipboard('text_general')">Copy general text</button>
```

This is my javascript code:

```
function copyToClipboard(elementId) {

    // Create a "hidden" input
    var aux = document.createElement("input");

    // Assign it the value of the specified element
    aux.setAttribute("value", document.getElementById(elementId).innerHTML);

    // Append it to the body
    document.body.appendChild(aux);

    // Highlight its content
    aux.select();

    // Copy the highlighted text
    document.execCommand("copy");

    // Remove it from the body
    document.body.removeChild(aux);

}
```

If the text in the textarea is: Hello! My name is "Lars".
Then I just copy "Hello! My name is".
So the text actally cuts before the quotation marks. anyone got a solution for this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should be doing `<?php echo htmlentities($text_general); ?>"` anyway, to prevent XSS, so try that.

Comment: Thanks @LawrenceCherone! Works perfect :)

Comment: yes htmlentities is more effective here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8353759/is-addslashes-safe-to-prevent-xss-in-a-html-attribute